# Is using multiple SSDs in RAID 0 good for reliability?

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0

I'm asking this because, unlike HDDs, the main lifetime limiting factor of an SSD is write cycles. By using RAID 0, it's effectively doubling the amount of write cycles usable, and theoretically should be more reliable with that. In practice, is it about the same?

**EDIT**: I do realise that in a RAID 0 setup, if one drive fails, all data is lost. However, this is mainly applicable in a RAID setup with traditional, mechanical Hard Drives, which can randomly fail at pretty much any stage of its life, but especially when its older, and are subject to damage caused by movement of the drive, etc. HDDs are obviously more prone to damage. *However*, I'm not talking about traditional Hard Drives. And what is the limiting factor of an SSD? ***Write cycles!*** In which, in a RAID 0 setup, each SSD is hit with **HALF** of the writes. Compared to having just one, or in a RAID 1 setup, in which all SSDs are hit with the FULL amount of write cycles, which would lessen the lifespan of an SSD, similarly to the reason why you should *never* defrag an SSD (but should trim). In theory, a RAID0 setup with SSDs, and only SSDs, should not only perform better but be more reliable. Because, in theory, it almost certainly should be. I'm not sure of any other limiting factors of SSDs except for reads potentially (which also would be reduced by a RAID 0 setup), but all of the comments on this post so far are *completely* dodging my question. This is my theory on RAID 0 with SSDs, backed up with the basic workings of an SSD compared to a Hard Drive, and how SSDs fail. I'm asking if, in practice, this would actually benefit. I'm probably going to ask the LTT forums because I know they actually know how to answer a simple yes or no question.

Comment: You understand if a single device in RAID 0 fail, then the entire RAID fails, right?  Why are you worried about the lifespan of SSD designed to last 5+ years with continous usage?

Comment: Raid 0 is Not Reliable as suggested by Ramhound

Comment: The 'main lifetime limiting factor of an SSD' is _not_ write cycles, but obsolescence. You will find it 'too small and slow' before it runs out of write cycles, as there will be larger and faster models on the market

Comment: I *really* encourage you to read [Are SSD drives as reliable as mechanical drives (2013)?](http://serverfault.com/q/507521/58408) over on [sf], which is our sister site for professional network and system administrators. When you are done reading that, you might also want to look over [What is the current state (2016) of SSDs in RAID?](http://serverfault.com/q/776564/58408) for some further insights. Executive summary: Write cycles are not a problem with modern SSDs, if you get one spec'd for your use case (or better). Electronics, however, can and do fail every once in a while.